# Symfony 4, disable twig cache

Tags: symfony4

From symfony 4, how doI disable the twig cache ?

When I edit an .html.twig file, I must clear the cache via the command './bin/console clear:cache' for me to see the updated result in my browser. I would like it to not execute each time the shell command.

In the config/packages/twig.yaml configuration file, I added :

```
auto_reload: '%kernel.debug%'
```

But nothing changes, I must still execute the cache:clear command each time I modify my templates files..

Comment: Are you running in development mode or production mode?

Comment: in my .env file, the "APP_ENV" variable is set to "dev"

Comment: Strange.  Twig templates normally recache automatically themselves when changed.  It could be that your attempts to disable the cache "broke" something.  Consider making a fresh S4 project, verify that your twig templates are indeed rebuilding themselves automatically and then try to determine what changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a slight delay, but...
Addition of `cache: false` to twig config should solve problem.

There you have full config options of twig:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html

Comment: the documentation says its not recommended : However, this is not recommended; not even in the dev environment, because the auto_reload option ensures that cached templates which have changed get compiled again.